# IntelliJ shows (Warning) error in JPQL

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote a query and use JPQl to fetch data

```
 @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "JpaQlInspection"})
    @Override
    public News getCurrentNews() {
        List<News> news = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from News where expiredAt>= :today " +
                "and startedAt<= :today order by createdAt desc , priority").
                setParameter("today", new Date()).list();

        return (news.isEmpty()) ? null : news.get(0);
    }
```

So, intelliJ show an error(or warning) and when i press Alt+Enter it offers 
to add

> @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "JpaQlInspection"})

What's that ?
What's used for ?
Is it wrong to put it or not ?

Comment: It would really help if you read (and told us) what the warning is (or what the warnings are). Also tell which Hibernate version you're using.

Comment: IntelliJ shows this message : "This inspection controls whether Persistance QL Queries are error-checked"

Answer (score 2):

@SuppressWarnings will tell the IDE to stop complaining about something. With my teams I don't allow it ever because it usually indicates a code smell. It is best to figure out why you are getting the warning.

In this case, your JPQL isn't valid. JPQL requires "SELECT"

```
SELECT N from News N where N.expiredAt>= :today
and N.startedAt<= :today " +
order by N.createdAt desc, N.priority
```

The reason it works is that HQL (Hibernate Query Language) supports leaving off the "SELECT" so it doesn't complain when you leave it off your JPQL. According to the spec though you are supposed to have it.

Comment: When i replaced this query with mine, it still shows 
This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked

Comment: I got 
" This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked" when i mouse over

Comment: ok. but the error suppression dialog should only show up if the query is showing an error. is there a separate error on the query itself?

Comment: No, but i want to understand why idea shows that message ?!